# Custom RetryPolicy in Spring doesn't retry

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-retry

I have the following configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyAppConfig {
@Value("${retry.backoff}")
private String retryBackoff;

@Bean
public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();

    FixedBackOffPolicy fixedBackOffPolicy = new FixedBackOffPolicy();
    fixedBackOffPolicy.setBackOffPeriod(Long.parseLong(retryBackoff));
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(fixedBackOffPolicy);

    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new CustomRetryPolicy());

    return retryTemplate;
  } 
}
```

Below is the component I created for my custom retry policy. Purpose of this policy is to improve it to retry only when certain HttpClientErrorExceptions happen.

```
@Component
public class CustomRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {

public void CustomRetryPolicy() {
    final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();

    simpleRetryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(5);

    this.setExceptionClassifier(new Classifier<Throwable, RetryPolicy>() {
        @Override
        public RetryPolicy classify(Throwable classifiable) {
            if (classifiable instanceof HttpClientErrorException) {

                return simpleRetryPolicy;
            }               
            return simpleRetryPolicy;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

This issue has no error log and retry does not happen. How can I fix this?

Comment: To enable Spring Retry in an application, we need to add the @EnableRetry annotation to our Configuration class:

Comment: When I tried with SimpleRetryPolicy instead of custom policy it didn't require @EnableRetry annotation.